# JSONP WCF Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, wcf, jsonp

I have my WCF contact defined below

```
   [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "GetUrlContent"

         )]
    List<string> GetUrlContent(List<string> urls);
}
```

I have

```
<binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
```

My JS looks like this

```
    var Url = "http://192.168.1.100/WebContent.svc/GetUrlContent?callback=?";
var postdata= [];
postdata.push("http://cnn.com");
postdata.push("http://bbc.com");

    $.getJSON(Url , JSON.stringify(postdata), function (msg) {
        for (i in msg) {

            console.log(msg[i]);
        }
    });
```

Err Msg i Get is

> "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed -
>   http://192.168.1.100/WebContent.svc/GetUrlContent?callback=jQuery183043170534494375234_1365725164391&[%22http://cnn.com%22,%22http://bbc.com%22]&_=1365725173310"

EDIT
This is my new Error message

```
 Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Operation 'GetUrlContent' in contract 'IFetchWebContent' uses GET, but also has body parameter 'urls'. GET operations cannot have a body. Either make the parameter 'urls' a UriTemplate parameter, or switch from WebGetAttribute to WebInvokeAttribute.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.ValidateGETHasNoBody(OperationDescription operation, String method)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass10.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetRequestDispatchFormatter>b__d()
```

Comment: I ran into this too a while back. I believe the issue is that the built-in JSONP support in WCF does not allow you to do `POST`, only `GET`.

Comment: that fixed it , but not i ran into different err:)

Comment: Please update your question to include the new error message.

Comment: @p.s.w.g i have updated it with new error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF's built-in JSONP support is limited to `GET` requests; you won't be able to do a `POST`.

Try changing your method to `GET`:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "GetUrlContent")]
List<string> GetUrlContent(List<string> urls);
```